# Can I set the default view to Page Width?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

The default is to open up with up to four whole pages showing with tiny text.

Can I change the default view/zoom to be Page Width instead?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the "defaults" are whatever normal.dotx is saved with. If you open this file, usually in

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Templates\
```

which is also

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
```

Open up that file (which, however, may be `normal.dotm`), adjust the file's zoom, save over that file, and then completely close out of Word.

Now, if you're talking about a specific file that always opens to that zoom, that's specific to that file. Save (over, or as a copy) after adjusting the zoom to your liking.